# Does PHP support conjunction and disjunction natively?

Tags: php, javascript

Javascript employs the conjunction and disjunction operators.

*The left–operand is returned if it can be evaluated as: false, in the case of conjunction (a && b), or true, in the case of disjunction (a || b); otherwise the right–operand is returned.*

Do equivalent operators exist in PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PHP supports short-circuit evaluation, a little different from JavaScript's conjunction.  We often see the example (even if it isn't good practice) of using short-circuit evaluation to test the result of a MySQL query in PHP:

```
// mysql_query() returns false, so the OR condition (die()) is executed.
$result = mysql_query("some faulty query") || die("Error");
```

Note that short-circuit evaluation works when in PHP when there is an expression to be evaluated on either side of the boolean operator, which would produce a return value.  It then *executes* the right side only if the left side is false.  This is different from JavaScript:

Simply doing:

```
$a || $b
```

would return a boolean value `TRUE` or `FALSE` if either is truthy or both are falsy.  It would *NOT* return the value of `$b` if `$a` was falsy:

```
$a = FALSE;
$b = "I'm b";

echo $a || $b;
// Prints "1", not  "I'm b"
```

So to answer the question, PHP will do a boolean comparison of the two values and return the result. It will not return the first truthy value of the two.

More idiomatically in PHP (if there is such a thing as idiomatic PHP) would be to use a ternary operation:

```
$c = $a ? $a : $b;

// PHP 5.3 and later supports
$c = $a ?: $b;
echo $a ?: $b;
// "I'm b"
```

#### Update for PHP 7

PHP 7 introduces [the `??` null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) which can act as a closer approximation to conjunction.  It's especially helpful because it doesn't require you to check `isset()` on the left operand's array keys.

```
$a = null;
$b = 123;
$c = $a ?? $b;
// $c is 123;
```

Comment: Javascript: `"first"||"second"` returns `"first"` whereas PHP `echo ("first"||"second")`will just return `1`. PHP does not return the left or right operands, only a boolean. Does PHP natively support the ability to return the actual operand is what I'm wondering.

Comment: @JordanArsenault Just updated my answer to include that, probably as you were typing.

Comment: Submitted that before I saw your edits. I guess what I'm looking for is not supported. Thanks for the explanation/clarification!

Comment: What  you want to use here is a ternary although the short-circuitting exists: echo ($first != '' ? $first : $second);

Comment: Thanks @MathieuDumoulin - I thought maybe there was a shortcut.

Comment: @JordanArsenault If you can use the new PHP 5.3 ternary shorthand, you'll get close: `$c = $a ?: $b;`