# Javascript-like syntax in php

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does PHP support conjunction and disjunction natively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065182/does-php-support-conjunction-and-disjunction-natively)

In javascript you can easily write something like that

```
var c = a || b;
```

it will set  c by value from a or from b it depends which one is previously defined.
it means that this bool operator || return value. But do we have the same approach in PHP ?

is there any short form of `$c = ($a) ? $a : ($b ? $b : null)`