# simple if statements (not short hand)

Tags: php, if-statement

So today, as everyday, I was programming. Going along my usual business, typing away, listening to Daft Punk and various other groovy tunes. Then out of the blue, I had to write something along the lines of:

```
$x = 'a'; // For instance

if ($x == 'a' || $x == 'b') {
    // ...
}
```

Simple enough, not too shabby I say. But wait! I thought to myself `"there must be an easier way to do that - I'm repeating myself"`. So I set about attempting to solve this with the following code:

```
if ($x == ('a' || 'b')) { 
    // ...
}
```

However, that doesn't work. At all. It's *always* true. If `$x` is equal to `a`, `b`, `c` or `cake`. So I sulked, cried a little bit and have decided to ask Stackoverflow if any of you guys know why.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PHP support conjunction and disjunction natively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065182/does-php-support-conjunction-and-disjunction-natively)

Comment: I think `('a' || 'b')` will always be true because 'a' and 'b' are non-zero values, therefore evaluating to one/true.

Comment: `if( in_array( $x, array( 'a', 'b')))` ?

Comment: +1 for no other reason than the awesome story.

Comment: +1 for awesome username and unique avatar

Answer (score 2):

`||` is the logical or, it evaluates the left side as boolean (`'a'`, which is in boolean context `true`) and if that's true returns true, if not, it does the same thing for the right hand side.

```
var_dump('a' || 'b');
bool(true)
```

Now, this value is compared against a character, which, based on the crazy rules of PHP ([loose comparison chart](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)), will also be true:

```
var_dump('a' == true);
bool(true)
```

Comment: and the funniest of all, `("string" == 0) => true`

Answer (score 1):

You're asking PHP to evaluate if `$x` is equal to the value of `('a' OR 'b')`, which will ALWAYS return `true` since both 'a' and 'b' have nonzero values.

You must use the comparison operator individually in this case, or use nickb's suggestion from the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't worked because

```
$a = 'a' || 'b'; // true, since 'a' and 'b' considered truthy
```

In this case, your string literals will be [converted to booleans.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)

And if your `$x` in the if is not an empty string or other string considered falsy they will be equal.

However you can write your if like this:

```
if (in_array($x, array('a', 'b', 'cake'))
```

If you feel that it makes your intent more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
$valid = array('a', 'b');

if (in_array($x, $valid)) {
    ...
}
```

Simple enough!

...but, in retrospect, maybe you didn't want another way to do it?

Comment: great, but that wasn't the question

Comment: +1 because it not only answered the question, but it gave an alternate solution as well.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Too late. Maybe I'll have to study the English language again: I've only done eight years.

Answer (score 1):

As you know || is a logical operator and always return true or false(in another word 1 or 0).
So, code ('a' || 'b') always return true(1). In this above case $x contains value so due to automatic type conversation $x also set to true(1) so its if(1 == 1) and return always true.

try with bellow code

```
$x = false;
if ($x == ('a' || 'b')) { echo 'true'; } else{ echo 'false';}
```

Always return false.

Answer (score 0):

See how php converts strings to boolean

```
php > var_dump((bool) "a");
bool(true)
php > var_dump((bool) "b");
bool(true)
php > var_dump((bool) "cake");
bool(true)
```

So basically you asking php if($x == true)

Answer (score 0):

see http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php