# Assign variable with the aid of boolean operators

Tags: php, variables, assign

Is there some short way to do this

```
if (!empty($b))
   $a = $b;
else if (!empty($c)) {
   $a  = $c;
```

i know you could use ternary operator but its not what i asking like in JavaScript there is way to assign like this

```
my_var = some_Var || fu_bar || 0;
```

so if first dont exist it uses second and if second dont exist it uses third one.

is there similar thing in php?

Comment: Which version? PHP 5.4 has `?:`

Comment: There isn't. In PHP, you'll just get a boolean.

Comment: What exactly qualifies as "empty"? Are the variables *nonexistent* (not defined) or may they simply be `null`. If the latter, is it only `null` or `== false`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PHP support conjunction and disjunction natively?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065182/does-php-support-conjunction-and-disjunction-natively)

Comment: @Álvaro `$my_var = ($some_Var ?: $fu_bar) ?: 0` comes reasonably close, assuming that both variables are set...

Comment: @deceze - The OP knows that. He's just asking whether the typical `start = offset || 0` JavaScript construct applies to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

cant think of other way than this:

```
 $a = ! empty($b) ? $b : (! empty($c) ? $c : 0)
```

Comment: "i know you could use ternary operator but its not what i['m] asking [for]"

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of the two ways whatever suits you. both of these functions will check either we have the non empty variable or not.

```
1: $a = (isset($b) && $b)?$b:$c;
2: if($b)
      $a = $b;
    elseif($c)
      $a = $c;
```